# Turn compose key into regular key

Tags: autohotkey

On my swiss french keyboard, the tilde `~` is a compose key, so to type a tilde, I have to hit <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>space</kbd> to confirm the key.

I'd like to add an autohotkey script to be able to hit <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> and have the tilde be entered directly without having to hit <kbd>space</kbd>.

I tried `>!VKDD::Send {ASC 126}` but it won't work. (I checked with a key hook and `DD` is the virtual key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

">!" is the symbol for the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key.  Try the AltGr symbol:

```
<^>!VKDD::Send {ASC 126}
```

or the scan code (SC) of the ^-key (on my system its the SC029):

```
<^>!SC029::Send {ASC 126}
```

Comment: Weird, I have been using ">!" everywhere else for altgr and it was working. Using the altgr symbol fixed it.